# MultiSelect ListBox Select And DeSelect Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listbox

I have a ListBox in winforms Application, now the business logic demands me to fire one function if an item in the List Box is Selected and fire another if an item in the List Box is Deselected.

But the way I see it none of the Events Listed in VS is giving that power of Execution. I do see Events like

```
SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and

```
SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

But both these event fires if there is a change in the selection of the ListBox. But it doesn't specify if an item was selected or deselected which raised the event.

Any suggestion on this would be very helpful.

I even found the following link on MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.unselected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But I am not sure how to apply the same in this situation.

Comment: One way is to maintain a list of selected items. Every time once of those events fires, check the current item against the list. If it does not exist you'll know it was just selected and can add it to the list, likewise if it does exist in the list you'll know it was deselected and can remove it.

Comment: Yes, I also thought of something similar, in which I would have to keep a note of the selected Items Count in a Global Variable in in my form Class and Act Accordingly. But that would be tedious for a simple requirement isn't?

Comment: The link you posted is for `WPF`, does not apply to `winforms`.

Comment: "But that would be tedious for a simple requirement isn't?" - Yup! I don't see another way, unless someone has already written a control that supports this that you can license.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Tedious Solution. Might help some1 in the future to Copy Paste.

```
public static int ListCount;

        private void listBoxPackService_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int CurrCount;

            ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection col = listBoxPackService.SelectedItems;
            CurrCount = col.Count;

            if (CurrCount > ListCount)
            {
                //Item Selected

            }
            else
            {
                //Item DeSelected

               if(CurrCount == 0)
               {
                  //All Items Were Deselected
               }

            }

            ListCount = CurrCount;

        }
```

On load of the ListBox

```
ListCount = 0
```

rename the Controls as per your requirement.

I am still open for a better solution :)